# How to apply search filter on JSON property with a space?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to filter on a json property with a space(Ex: Last Name) in a search field, I am able to access and print JSON property with a space, but I am unable to filter the JSON property with a space. How to apply filter on JSON property with a space in a search field?

```
        <div ng-init="jsonData()">   
            <table border="1" class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Age</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in result | filter:searchText">
                        <td>{{x['First Name']}}</td>
                        <td>{{x['Last Name']}}</td>
                        <td>{{x.Age}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a [custom AngularJS filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) and use JavaScript's `.trim()` function on the search text.

Example:

```
 angular.module('myModule', [])
    .filter('searchTextWithSpaces', function() {
       return function(array, searchText) {
          searchText = searchText.trim();
          array = array.filter(function(obj) {
               return obj["Last Name"].trim().indexOf(searchText) !== -1;
          });
          return array;
       }
    };
})
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I added an example, see the documentation for more references.

Comment: I am trying to apply filter on a specific column with spaces in json data @BenBeck

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plunker with a working example :

http://plnkr.co/edit/XNMhaPs7gcBDvU0xZm0l

I didn't make a lot of changes and it just worked. 
This is space in JSON Object property and value. Hope that helps !

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="SampleController">

    Search by Last Name
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchText">

    <table border="1" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="x in result | filter:searchText">
                    <td>{{x['first name']}}</td>
                    <td>{{x['last name']}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('SampleController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.result = [
     {"first name": "John", "last name": "Doctor Watson"}, 
     {"first name": "Peter", "last name": "Doctor Who"}, 
     {"first name": "Sherlock", "last name": "Holmes"}, 
     {"first name": "James", "last name": "Moriarty"}        
    ];       

});
```

Comment: I am trying to apply filter on a specific column with JSON data in spaces, how to solve this problem?

Comment: My plunker example apply filter on specific `last name` column with spaces in data. Try to type `doctor who` in textbox for example and see what happens. Isn't it what you tried to achieve ?